# Laravel isolate admin login

Tags: laravel, authentication, admin

I've made a CMS without user front-end. Only admin panel is active, and I would like to restrict anyone who is not admin from logging in.

I have made an `isAdmin()` method in `User` model:

```
public function isAdmin()
    {
        if ($this->roles->first()->name == 'Administrator') {
            return true;
        }else return false;
    }
```

Which works fine (I have tested the feedback).

Everything outside the `Route::auth();` is protected with middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function () {
   ...
});
```

I have registered 'admin' middleware in Kernel, and it's handle method is:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()){
            return redirect('user');
        }else return redirect('login');
    }
```

But the problem I have is that I get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`, and something doesn't work as it should? Does anyone know why?

**EDIT:**

Logic suggests that when middleware is triggered that each request will be redirected to user, so i changed it to:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()){
            return $next($request);
        }else return redirect('login');
    }
```

Which works for admin users, but for other users, they don't get redirected, but I get the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` again

Comment: Could you paste the output of  "php artisan route:list"

Comment: It is huge...I have many models and API and Front-end routes. Which route are you interested in?

Comment: The login route (GET)

Comment: It's a standard Laravel auth route which calls AuthController@showLoginForm

Comment: Verify that you are not adding any middleware to that route.

Comment: No, web and guest only

Comment: Is the post login route under the web middleware?

Comment: if it's laravel 5.1 then redirect to 'auth/login' not just 'login'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that `RedirectIfAuthenticated` is giving me problems because it is redirecting to home (which is protected with middleware also), and then the middleware is redirecting it to login, and it never gets out of the route, so my solution was to logout user in order to break the started session:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()){
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect('login');
        }
    }
```